# There is a Empty character in my Character Array at the end and idkwhy

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * stack = NULL;
int top = -1;

void push (char letter);
void pop();

int main()
{
    char stringy [100];
    stack = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter a String : ");
    scanf("%s",stringy);

    char letter = '1';
    for (int i = 0 ; letter != '\0'; i++){
        letter = stringy[i];
        push(letter);
        printf("Top = %d, Character = %c",top,letter);
    }

    top--;
    for (top; top != -1; top){
        pop();
    }
    return 0;
}

void push(char letter){
    top++;
    stack[top] = letter;
}

void pop(){
    
    printf("%c",stack[top]);
    top--;
}
```

THERE IS A EMPTY CHARACTER THAT IS BEING PUSHED AND I DONT KNOW WHY PLEASE HELP
There is a fourth element being pushed into my stack as well which has no display on the stdout.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to debug your own code. Run it in a debugger and trace it as it executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this loop in your code:

```
    for (int i = 0; letter != '\0'; i++){
        letter = stringy[i];
        push(letter);
```

When the value of `i` is equal to index of `stringy` array where null character exists (i.e. `stringy[i] is '\0'`, it will first assign that `'\0'` character to `letter` and then that null character is pushed to stack.

Instead of checking `letter != '\0'`, you should directly check the `stringy[i] != '\0'` in `for` loop condition.

Few other problems in your code:

In `main()` function, you are doing

```
    top--;
    for (top; top != -1; top){
        pop();
    }
```

It can be implemented in a better way, like this:

```
    while (top != -1) {
        pop();
    }
```

A suggestion - Instead of printing character in `pop()` function, better to return the character, popped from stack, from `pop()` function.

Since, the size of `stringy` array is `100` characters, put a restriction in `scanf()` to not to read more than `99` characters (the remain one character space is for null terminating character):

```
    scanf("%99s",stringy);
```

Follow good programming practice, always check `malloc` function return and `free` the dynamically allocated memory once your program done with it.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * stack = NULL;
int top = -1;

void push (char letter);
void pop();

int main (void) {
    char stringy [100];

    stack = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    if (stack == NULL) {
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter a String : ");
    scanf("%99s",stringy);

    for (int i = 0; stringy[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        push(stringy[i]);
        printf("Top = %d, Character = <%c>\n", top, stringy[i]);
    }

    while (top != -1) {
        pop();
    }

    free (stack);
    return 0;
}

void push(char letter) {
    top++;
    stack[top] = letter;
}

void pop() {
    printf("%c",stack[top]);
    top--;
}
```

A stack data structure can be implemented in much better way. Leaving it up to you to learn and modify the implementation.

Comment: Oh i understand now. Really silly mistake sorry to waste your time. Still learning. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: I am really sorry i am still learning. I understand now and will work more on stacks and better coding practices, thank you so much for being so thorough and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your program had few bugs. I fixed those. Now, it is working correctly.

There were two changes:

1. The condition in the for loop was changed.
2. top-- was removed from the main() function.

The updated code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stack = NULL;
int top = -1;

void push (char letter);
void pop();

int main()
{
    char stringy [100];
    stack = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter a String : ");
    scanf("%s",stringy);

    char letter = '1';

    for (int i = 0 ; ((letter = stringy[i]) != '\0'); i++){
        push(letter);
        printf("Top = %d, Character = %c\n",top,letter);
    }

    for (top; top != -1; top) {
        pop();
    }

    return 0;
}

void push(char letter)
{
    top++;
    stack[top] = letter;
}

void pop()
{
    printf("%c",stack[top]);
    top--;
}
```

Comment: I understand now. was a silly mistake on my part, I am still learning. Thank You so much for your time :)